# AngularJS access element from controller in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am kind of newbie in AngularJS world, and I'm running into a problem I have't been able to solve.
I have a nested ng-repeat view, because I have a nested comment system, so I build the view from an object that is like this:

```
comments: [{
  _id: ObjectId(x),
  parent_id: ObjectId(y),
  text: 'Hello World!',
  author: {
    id: 1,
    name: Jorge
  }
  replies: [{
    _id: ...,
    parent_id: ...
    author: {
      [...]
    }
    replies: [{
      [...]
    }]
  },
  {
    [...]
  }]
}]
```

So, every comment have a property named `hearts` which are the number of likes that it has.
I have socket.io implemented so this is all running in real-time. In my controller I have a listener for a new like to a comment, the problem is, how I access a specific comment from my controller to update it likes?

I have tried by generating a dynamic id in the view like this `ng-attr-id="{{'hearts_' + comment._id}}"` but this is just working for the parents comments, not for the replies, and I don't know why.

I have also tried to generate a function that looks for the comments and updates it, for instance this function:

```
    var setNewHearts = function(comments, comment) {
      for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        if ((String(comments[i]._id)) == (String(comment._id))) {
          comments[i].hearts = eventData.comment.hearts;
          return comments;
        } else if (comments[i].replies) {
          setNewHearts(comments[i].replies, eventData.comment);
        } else {
          //$scope.showMoreComments = true;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(eventData.comment);
    $scope.comments = setNewHearts($scope.comments, eventData.comment);
```

but with this function my $scope doesn't get updated in real-time, because I don't have the path to do it, I mean for example `$scope.comments[2].replies[0].replies[3].replies[1]`

I hope someone could help me with this because I am going mad! I have read something about directives. Could this be my solution?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive directive makes the most sense, but Angular causes an infinite loop with recursive directives and it's a bit ugly to workaround. You can use `ng-include` recursively like this: [**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/hifeyuwixi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-include="'comment.html'"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template"  id="comment.html">
  <div>
    <p>{{comment.author.name}}: {{comment.text}}</p>
    <div class="reply" ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" ng-include="'comment.html'"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

This is the sample data I used:

```
  $scope.comments = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Hello World!',
      author: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jorge'
      },
      replies: [
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Hey, Jorge!',
          author: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'World'
          },
          replies: [
            {
              id: 3,
              text: 'Woah!',
              author: {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Jorge'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

For the updating when the socket message comes in, I would do this:

```
socket.on('comment-liked', function(commentId) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    // recursively search all objects and return object where `obj.id === commentId`
    var comment = findCommentById($scope.comments, likedCommentId);
    // increment the counter or set to 1 if there were no hearts before
    comment.hearts = comments.hearts ? ++comment.hearts : 1;
  });
});
```

Here's my function to get an array of matching comments. It uses lodash/underscore `flatten`, but you could do that manually pretty easily if you want. It's best to be using npm modules so you can easily include lodash's flatten without bulking up your code with the whole library =D

```
function findCommentById(comments, id) {
  return _.flatten(comments.map(function(comment) {
    if (comment.id === id) { return comment; }
    return findCommentById(comment.replies, id);
  }))[0];
}
```

As you can see in [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/xejojaroti/1/edit?html,js,output), the comment is updated as you wish.

Comment: Yeah! No problem with that, I'm showing correctly my nested comments. Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly but the problem now I have all of those nested comments, I need to access specific ones from my controller to change some of their attributes. For example, accessing the comment with id == 3 (in your example) and changing its author, and showing it live in real-time.

Comment: As I said, maybe I'm not explaining right myself, but I have events on the controller (client-side) fired from the server-side. In the client-side listener I got the comment.id and I want to change it and show the result live.@m59 I'm upvoting your comment because It's a solution to the nested problem!!

Comment: @Jorge I would just iterate through the `comments` and change what you need. It's easy on principle, but a bit complex searching deeply through all those arrays/objects. I'm working on a clean solution.

Comment: Yeah! The function that I posted in the question is working ok, the problem is that I don't get my view updated. I can't even splice and push again in $scope.comments... This is kind of hard to me. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Jorge oh, lol. You just need to call $scope.$apply(), I bet. You probably are using a websocket that doesn't inform Angular when something happens, just like DOM events.

Comment: I didn't post it but I'm calling $scope.$apply() and it is not updating the view. I'm using socket.io for server->client events. The last line `$scope.comments = setNewHearts($scope.comments, eventData.comment);` deletes my $scope.comments and just let the updated comment, obviously :(

Comment: @Jorge Sorry, that function is hard to follow. You don't need to delete the comments and start over. You just need to replace the data within the object. It's more efficient anyway. Does my updated answer help?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't want to write so much code that this become unreadable but I think it is the opposite... That is the first I tried but it doesn't update the view!! Should it? Maybe I'm doing something wrong in other part of the code... Thank you @m59!!

Comment: @Jorge The code in my updated answer works, and looks nice. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So as your answer is working I am marking your answer as accepted. I will try to make my code work and I will update if I keep having issues. Thank you again!